# How to set lengths only for a specific environment (parindent for paracol in this case)?

Tags: environments, indentation, paragraphs, lengths, parallel

Is it possible to set a length specifically for an environment? I know it is possible to change lengths for parts of the document only, by placing the `\setlength` command between `{}`, but when using an environment many times in a document, it would be quite cumbersome to set the length as many times as the environment is used.

In my specific case I would like to change `\parindent` only for the `paracol` environment, but not for the rest of the document. An MWE of my problem is this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{paracol,lipsum,microtype}
\usepackage[norsk,british]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{paracol}{2}
    \newlength{\LeftHeader}
    \switchcolumn[0]*[\subsection*{Norwegian\settowidth{\LeftHeader}{Norwegian}\hspace{0.5\textwidth}\hspace{-\LeftHeader} English}]
        \selectlanguage{norsk} Universitetet i Oslo ble opprettet 2. september 1811, eller det vil si: Den gangen het det Det kongelige Frederiks Universitet, og det gjorde det helt frem til 1939.
    \switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{british} The University of Oslo was founded the second of september 1811, or actually: then it was called The royal Frederiks University, and it did so until 1939.
    \switchcolumn*
        \selectlanguage{norsk} Påls mor ble født syv år senere, unnfanget i de elleville fredsdager, født en kald februarlørdag i 1946.
    \switchcolumn
        \selectlanguage{british} Paul's mother was born seven years earlier, conceived during those wild days of peace, born on a cold february saturday in 1946.
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\parindent` should be maintained at the green block, but be removed at the red blocks. How does one change this length only for the `paracol` environment, and for *all* `paracol` environments that are used throughout the document?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since environments define a group, you can update/define commands within it and it will remain local to that environment. So setting `\parindent` to `0pt` inside `paracol` would suffice.

#### Global approach

For a more global approach, adding

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox
\AtBeginEnvironment{paracol}{\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}}
```

works and provides a consistent non-invasive way of achieving your goal.

#### Local/manual approach

Start each `paracol` with

```
\begin{paracol}{<num>}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
  ...
\end{paracol}
```

In both instances, the result yields:

[image]

Comment: It is that last bit about the global approach that does it (and beautifully, without any hacking with renewing environments and all), may I suggest placing that on top?

Comment: @Betohaku: Since these posts may be applicable to a wider audience, others may want more localized control over settings. We can keep it this way until the universe decides otherwise. `:)`

Comment: Of course the placing on top was meant for the audience as well, as it wouldn't do anything for me now anymore, would it? :p I just wondered the global thing would match the question (which is about global settings) better. Thanks again.

Comment: @Betohaku: Okay, I've shortened the post with the global approach first, followed by a manual/local approach.